# Dart OOP programming

Tags: dart, oop, angular-dart, dart-pub, dart-html

Question: The challenge is to create a program that has the following features
An object-oriented model that uses classes and inheritance
A class that implements an interface
A class that overrides an inherited method
An instance of a class that is initialized with data from a file
A method that demonstrates the use of a loop

I try to create a scenerario but I guess I'm getting it right

Comment: This article should help you https://dart.dev/language/classes